# Issues with sending out text by using PHPMailer class

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer 5.2.9 and trying to send out a newsletter. Having trouble with mail delivering issues if the body text contains the words `late` and `Soma`. e.g.

```
$message='Son of late Josinho Soma Project';
```

If either of the words `late` or `Soma` is taken off, the email is delivered successfully. I have also tried changing `Soma` to `Somm` as below and could see the email was delivered.

```
$message='Son of late Josinho Somm Project';
```

I have also tried sending out the same text using a simple PHP mail function having no issues. Not sure, what is causing the issue with the PHPMailer class.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a spam filter, either by your provider or by the recipient of the mail.

Comment: If you're seeing an error, you need to tell us what it is. PHPMailer does no filtering. I suggest you set `SMTPDebug = 3` so that you can see what happens when delivering your message; if you're using `isMail()`, you will need to check your mail server logs to see what is happening to the message.